# Show a View Controller conditionally via method

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a class that segues to different avenues, I would like to cut the code down as much as possible by creating one method that segues a VC conditionally. But I

```
-(void)segueToViewController {

}
```

But I don't know how to do this with other view controllers subclassed.

Normally you would do this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
SignInViewController *signInVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignInViewController"];
[self presentViewController:signInVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

But what if we don't know the Class name for `segueToViewController`? I've tried alot of things but can't figure it out. You'll probably down vote me for this but whatever it takes to get a solution. At least I've tried to do this on my own. I'm first to say my basic knowledge in the difference of ID to UIViewController is minimal:

```
-(void)segueToViewController:(id)viewController {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someVCID"];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

This question is because my button will select a random Class from n classes to instantiate, so instead of a long `if condition` or `switch method` I would like to keep it simple as the above in one method

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, have an array with all the storyboard identifiers of the view controllers you want to choose from. Then you randomly pick one of them and call:

```
    - (void)segueToViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
```

Comment: why would I do that when I can get the identifier using the restorationIdentifier property? I'm just asking how do you do it when you don't know the Class name to call. I don't know if it's going to be SignInViewController or LogInViewController or HomeViewController class

Comment: Firstly the restoration identifier isn't always the same as the storyboard identifier. Secondly to use the restoration identifier, even if it is the same as the storyboard identifier, you already need to have an instantiated view controller with that restoration identifier and why wouldn't you just use that view controller, instead of creating another one? Unless you need multiple SignIn, LogIn or Home view controllers, which seems unlikely.

Comment: I used those names as an example to show they are different, not that those were the actual View Controllers. The restorationIdentifier _is_ always the same if you click the button that says "Use Storyboard ID" which I have done. And you don't need an already instantiated vc you can just use the property `someVC.restorationIdentifier`

Comment: Of course you can do that, but if you call `someVC.restorationIdentifier` before `someVC` is instantiated it will be `nil`...

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can do with the segue identifier.

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Segue Name Here"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any value or object to the view controller here, like
        [vc setObject:object];
    }
}
```

Comment: No. This is exactly what I would like to avoid. I don't want to use if conditions as stated in my question. I want to use one method for all view controller classes